# SQL Generate Group Number Base on Parent Line

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a ordered table here, the Parent_Flag column tells you which row is the parent and the following child would be put in the same group.
How can I create the desired_result column in SQL?

Example:

```
ID   Parent_Flag Desired_Result
001      P           1
001      C           1
001      C           1
002      P           2
002      C           2
002      P           3
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: sql-server. Thanks!

Comment: I think you might need a better example, because this one isn't making much sense (to me at least).

Comment: Basically I am trying to create a sub group and used some criteria to generate the Parent_Flag column. A value P in the Parent_Flag column and all the subsequent C will be put in the same group, until the next P then it will be the start of the next group.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Group number, as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL server 2012+:

using a conditional aggregation window function `sum()` or `count()` with [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

note: I added an `identity` column to the sample data to derive an order for the rows.

```
select *
  , grp = sum(case when Parent_flag = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by i)
  , cgrp = count(case when Parent_flag = 'P' then 1 end) over (order by i)
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SMLN40470

returns:

```
+---+-----+-------------+-----+------+
| i | id  | parent_flag | grp | cgrp |
+---+-----+-------------+-----+------+
| 1 | 001 | P           |   1 |    1 |
| 2 | 001 | C           |   1 |    1 |
| 3 | 001 | C           |   1 |    1 |
| 4 | 002 | P           |   2 |    2 |
| 5 | 002 | C           |   2 |    2 |
| 6 | 002 | P           |   3 |    3 |
+---+-----+-------------+-----+------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much SqlZim :)